# Dot Net Nuke Site Aliases

Tags: dotnetnuke

My DNN woes continue. The site alias was s-fr-dnn/MNTCDNN/accr2011 (I didn't set this up). It was suggested I remove the MNTCDNN portion of the alias (now it is s-fr-dnn/accr2011). I did so, and now I get "resource not found errors". So, I decided to change it back to s-fr-dnn/MNTCDNN/accr2011, but I keep getting a "This site alias is invalid" error. How can it be invalid? It was just labeled as such.

In ISS, there is the default website and under that is MNTCDNN (if this helps at all).

Any clue to what is wrong here?

Comment: I could not figure out how to change this back through the interface so I just modified it through the sql module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik,

A few thoughts.

1. TO remove a virtual directory from the path, you will have to physically move the files on the server.  This is why your first round attempt was an issue.
2. Regarding your change, since you made the change directly in the database, DNN heavily caches portal aliases.  You will need to recycle the application pool for your changes to be available.